# Error running command (re-run needed): invalid type: floating point `18446744073709552000`, expected u64

Tags: solana-cli, candy-machine

when im trying to deploy my candy-machine, im getting this error.i am trying to deploy my candy machine but i can't deploy it. need to feelup my assignment . how to solve it? i dont know what to do. how to deploy and how to us UI for candy machine?